# Волосы его от ветра развевались по воздуху. Нет ли скрытой тавтологии?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология, редактура

Если можно оставить предложение в таком виде, нет ли других недочетов, вроде не *развевались по воздуху*, а *развевались в воздухе*. Или это все область синонимии?

Comment: Юлия, Вам надо **определиться**: развИвались или развЕвались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Волосы его развевались на ветру.**

Тавтологии нет, выражение используется в литературе, но воздух ― лишнее слово (не несет никакой информации).

Сравнить: Над страной весенний **ветер веет.**..

Там, вдали, вдруг проскакали лошади, на них сидели дамы, и их белые платья **развевались на ветру**. [Людмила Петрушевская. Город Света // «Октябрь», 2003]